# which pygame is needed for python 2.7.6?

Tags: pygame

which version of pygame should I install for python 2.7.6?
I have tried a lot of versions but none of them work!
is it necessary to install pygame in a specific location?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just run:

```
pip install pygame
```

or

```
easy_install pygame
```

and it will automatically pick the best version.